# Solving degree 3 equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, factoring, cubics

Solve for $x$,

\begin{cases}4x^3+3x^2y+y^3=8\\
2x^3-2x^2y+xy^2=1\end{cases}

I tried substitution of $x$, but it got very complex.
Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x%5E3%2B3x%5E2y%2By%5E3%3D8%2C2x%5E3-2x%5E2y%2Bxy%5E2%3D0) finds the real solution $x=0,y=2$ (which I found by inspection), two complex solutions with $x=0, y$ the other two cube roots of $8$, and some messy complex solutions.

Comment: Is there any other simpler way other than inspection?

Comment: I don't think there is a simpler method than inspection when it works.  The problem is that it often doesn't.  Here I got one root out of nine that way, three if I had thought about the complex cube roots of $8$.  When the solutions are messy usually there isn't a simple way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a simpler way, since these equations are homogeneous we can substitute $$y=ax$$ which will make the equation simpler to solve.

Substituting it in both the equations we get,
$$x^3[4+3a+a^3]=8$$ and
$$x^3[2-2a+a^2]=1$$,

Dividing these two and simplifying we get 
$$a^3-8a^2+19a-12=0$$

Which factors to 
$$[a-1][a-3][a-4]=0$$

Putting $a=1$ in either of the equations we get $$x=y=1$$

I believe you can now put $a=3,4$ in the equation yourself and get the answer

Comment: But the second equation is 0

Comment: I think if we reverse the ratio, it will become 0.

Answer (score 2):

We obtain:
$$4x^3+3x^2y+y^3=8(2x^3-2x^2y+xy^2)$$ or
$$12x^3-19x^2y+8xy^2-y^3=0$$ or
$$12x^3-12x^2y-7x^2y+7xy^2+xy^2-y^3=0$$ or
$$(x-y)(12x^2-7xy+y^2)=0$$ or
$$(x-y)(3x-y)(4x-y)=0.$$
Can you end it now?

I got the following answer:
$$\left\{(1,1),\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]5},\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]5}\right), \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{10}},\frac{4}{\sqrt[3]{10}}\right)\right\}$$